# Generating N Prime Numbers

Tags: performance, primes, vb.net

I'm trying to generate *N* prime numbers where my *N* = 200,000.

The method that *I think* I wrote is -

> 1. Start with first prime of **2**
> 2. Increment possible prime number by 1
> 3. See if possible prime is divisible by any found prime (if yes exit to 2)
> 4. Stop testing when next found prime is more than half of the possible prime (exit to 2)
> 5. Add it to the list

*It works*, but it is taking **1 minute 8 seconds** which seems *really long*. Is my algorithm not doing what I think or is it just implemented incorrectly? Or should I not be using these arrays?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
Option Compare Text
Module PrimeNumberGenerator
     Sub Main()
        Static start_time As DateTime
        Static end_time As DateTime
        Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan
        start_time = DateTime.Now
        Dim targetPrimes(199999) As Integer
        targetPrimes = GetPrimes(targetPrimes.Length)
        end_time = DateTime.Now
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        Debug.Print(elapsed_time.ToString)
        Debug.Print((targetPrimes(500)).ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetPrimes(ByVal countOfPrimes As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim myPrimes(countOfPrimes - 1) As Integer
        Dim primeIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim testIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim possiblePrime As Integer = 2
        myPrimes(primeIndex) = possiblePrime
        Do Until primeIndex = countOfPrimes - 1
            possiblePrime += 1
            For testIndex = 0 To primeIndex
                If possiblePrime Mod myPrimes(testIndex) = 0 Then
                    Continue Do
                ElseIf myPrimes(testIndex + 1) * 2 > possiblePrime Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            primeIndex += 1
            myPrimes(primeIndex) = possiblePrime
        Loop
        Return myPrimes
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One speed tweak is to search to only the square root of the 'possiblePrime'.  This will reduce computation by a significant order of magnitude.

Another tweak is to add 2, instead of 1 to 'possiblePrime' as you know that all even numbers > 2 are not prime.

Comment: I can't put my finger on it yet, but the inner `For` loop doesn't appear as elegant as I think it could be.

Comment: Just those two points alone got the process down to under 1 second. Huh.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer 'elegant loops' - code that does not have implicit or explicit breaks. Not always easy to achieve, and there are times when it appears impossible. I also prefer 'positive loops' where the continuation is based on a positive explicit statement rather than a negative or combination of negative statements. Sometimes this latter preference can be satisified through a slight tweak of a variable.

I have been looking at the inner `For` loop, it has two breaks in continuity (`Continue Do` and `Exit For`).

> ```
>     Do Until primeIndex = countOfPrimes - 1
>         possiblePrime += 1
>         For testIndex = 0 To primeIndex
>             If possiblePrime Mod myPrimes(testIndex) = 0 Then
>                 Continue Do
>             ElseIf myPrimes(testIndex + 1) * 2 > possiblePrime Then
>                 Exit For
>             End If
>         Next
>         primeIndex += 1
>         myPrimes(primeIndex) = possiblePrime
>     Loop
> ```

Which could also be achieved by:

```
    Dim continueLooking as Boolean, primeFound as Boolean ' loop management
    Do Until primeIndex = countOfPrimes - 1
        possiblePrime += 1
        testIndex = 0
        continueLooking = True
        primeFound = True ' seems counterintuitive to start off at True!
        While continueLooking
            'First check
            If possiblePrime Mod myPrimes(testIndex) = 0 Then
                continueLooking = False
                primeFound = False
            Else
            'Second check
                continueLooking = (Math.Pow(myPrimes(testIndex + 1),2) > possiblePrime)
            End If
        End While 'Wend
        If primeFound then
            primeIndex += 1
            myPrimes(primeIndex) = possiblePrime
        End If
    Loop
```

Obviously, some more internal management has been used to achieve the elegance, trade-offs always exist.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue, you could use a random number generator followed by a [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Heuristic_tests), this is usually faster for big numbers, but if you stay limited to 32 bits ones I'm not sure if it will be faster.

Comment: Link only answer is not really helpfull, could you explain how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Just implementing AJD's recommendations (compare to square root of test value, add 2 each time). This should be significantly faster.

```
Private Function GetPrimes(ByVal countOfPrimes As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim myPrimes(countOfPrimes - 1) As Integer
    Dim primeIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim testIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim possiblePrime As Integer = 1
    myPrimes(0) = 2
    Do Until primeIndex = countOfPrimes - 1
        possiblePrime += 2
        For testIndex = 0 To primeIndex
            If possiblePrime Mod myPrimes(testIndex) = 0 Then
                Continue Do
            ElseIf myPrimes(testIndex) >= Math.Sqrt(possiblePrime) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        primeIndex += 1
        myPrimes(primeIndex) = possiblePrime
    Loop
    Return myPrimes
End Function
```

Comment: Nope. possiblePrime starts at 1, adds 2 each iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading it like mine, sorry